# Is there a way to trigger autocomplete programatically based on a keydown event?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, rendering

We are trying to use Autocomplete component to enable our users, search for a few features of our application.
It is currently configured to use freeSolo, and a few input handlers using onChange, onInputChange etc. and results are being fetched as expected upon character entry.

Transitioning from a prior app which lets users hit the search button to get results asynchronously, we are expected to support 'enter' key, upon pressing, should fetch the results and render them.

However, We could not find a way to render options upon a key down event on 'Enter', if the results were not already rendered (for example, when the search input lost focus because of an 'Escape' event or 'Tab' or other such scenarios).

code sandbox  - https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-xpjvv?file=/demo.js
Have added a comment in the above code snippet to cite the exact problem we are facing in the 'Enter' event handler. Couldn't find appropriate API from the below doc to render results
https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

Every Autocomplete component have these concerns:

1. keeping the input value `onChange`. exactly like what you do.
2. Show some suggestion based on user input using **throttle or debounce** on `onKeyPress` to avoid repetitively call the API endpoint which probably cost a fortune.
3. Show the final result or redirect the user to the `search` page on `enter` or on click on every rendered suggestion, that you've already done this part.

Comment: Perhaps, I may not have presented my problem adequately. Showing results on 'Autocomplete' results popup programmatically, is what i am looking for.

Updated description to point to the section of code we are lost at